# Erstwhile, meanwhile, and _?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

If past is to present as erstwhile is to meanwhile, then present is to future as meanwhile is to *thing*while.

What is the actual word that *thing* in the above statement refers to?

Sometimes you hear people say that such and such will happen in "**the** next [**little**] while", so I'm wondering if the possible neologism *nextwhile* would suit. Does a term like this exist?

Which grammatical categories erstwhile and meanwhile belong to is a related issue. It does not seem so much as an adverb as a noun, being typically prefixed with *the*.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143012/discussion-on-question-by-lucky-erstwhile-meanwhile-and); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.